# Add to array inside of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript object that is `DYNAMICALLY CREATED` like this

```
[
  {"user":"James","errors":["signature must be signed!"]},
  {"user":"Jones","errors":["signature must be signed!"]}
]
```

I am trying to dynamically add a new error in `errors` array inside that object.

This is what i have tried:

```
validationErr.push({ "user" : "James", "errors" : ["start time musst be filled!"] });
```

But i get a new entry

```
[
  {"user":"James","errors":["signature must be signed!"]},
  {"user":"Jones","errors":["signature must be signed!"]},
  {"user" : "James", "errors" : ["start time musst be filled!"]}
]
```

instead of this

```
[
  {"user":"James","errors":["signature must be signed!", "start time musst be filled!"]},
  {"user":"Jones","errors":["signature must be signed!"]},
]
```

How can I add to existing array inside my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit ugly, but you can achieve what you'd like assuming you have unique users and `errors` field is never undefined;

```js
function func(arr, idField, id, updField, upd) {
     arr.find(obj => obj[idField] == id)[updField].push(upd);
}

validationErr = [
  {"user":"James","errors":["signature must be signed!"]},
  {"user":"Jones","errors":["signature must be signed!"]}
];

func(validationErr, "user", "James", "errors", "start time must be filled!");

console.log(validationErr);
```

Using `find()` to get the first occurrence with correct user name, and push into its array, with one-liner.

Comment: @lewis4u yes, if user == James is unique, you'd get a single one in the array after filtering, so would need to fetch it with that selector.

Comment: what if my object is dynamically created?

Comment: @lewis4u You can still pass the fields as parameters, but the zero will stay assuming the filter condition will always result a single result. Updated my answer to have parametric field selects

Comment: @lewis4u Why do you think this is the best answer? It iterates the whole array even if the first element is the one you want. Using `some` or `find` as suggested by Nina would be much better as they stop the iteration as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 solution using [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
const data=[{user:"James",errors:["signature must be signed!"]},{user:"Jones",errors:["signature must be signed!"]}];

function addError(username, error){
   const {errors} = data.find(({user})=>user===username);
   if(errors){ errors.push(error) }
}

addError("James", "error occured");
console.log(data)
```

Comment: what is `return false;` doing with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: @NinaScholz must have confused it with the jQuery each function.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and find the right user. Then push error and exit the loop.

If no user is found, a new object is created with the `errors` array.

```js
function addError(user, error) {
    if (!data.some(function (a) {
        if (a.user === user) {
            a.errors.push(error);
            return true;
        }
    })) {
        data.push({ user: user, errors: [error] });
    }
}

var data = [{ user: "James", errors: ["signature must be signed!"] }, { user: "Jones", errors: ["signature must be signed!"] }];

addError("James", "start time musst be filled!");
addError("foo", "bar");

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
function addError(user, error) {
    var object = data.find(a => a.user === user);
    if (object) {
        object.errors.push(error);
    } else {
        data.push({ user, errors: [error] });
    }
}

var data = [{ user: "James", errors: ["signature must be signed!"] }, { user: "Jones", errors: ["signature must be signed!"] }];

addError("James", "start time musst be filled!");
addError("foo", "bar");

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Maybe i am making a mistake creating an object? What about Gaurav answer?

Comment: that is an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and effective approach to do it is:

```
validationErr[validationErr.map((e)=>e.user).indexOf('James')].errors.push("value");
```

or like this

```
validationErr[validationErr.findIndex(e => e.user === 'James')].errors.push("value");
```

This took **0.03 ms** vs **find()** method approach which took **0.07 ms**. **200% faster** on an average!

Although, fastest method is to use key-value pair but you can't use this approach since your object is being dynamically generated

```js
var ValidationErr = {};

ValidationErr['James'] = [];
ValidationErr['Robby'] = [];
ValidationErr['James'].push("Not Authenticated");
ValidationErr['James'].push("Wrong Credentials");
ValidationErr['Robby'].push("No Error");

console.log(ValidationErr['James']);
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? I want to hear more comments on this because i find this also a good solution!

Comment: @lewis4u I have revised my answer. Earlier, I didn't read the question carefully as I was in a hurry then. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should push inside the object with that specific key.

Then your syntax must be;

```
validationErr[0].errors.push("start time musst be filled!");
```

Where `validationErr[0]` gives you object with james and push to his errors.

Comment: Hmm it is dynamically created so I think this would not be a good solution, because your solution is hardcoded!